# Are the songs on the Pipboy Radio original to the game?

Tags: fallout-4, game-music-identification

This morning I awoke to the usual chaos of a battlefield, with what seemed to be classical music playing in the background, courtesy of my Dad playing Fallout 4. As I was getting up, the song changed, and I actually liked it.

I found out that my Dad had been on *Classical Radio*, on the Pipboys radio section, so I am wondering if the songs that play on these channels are original or if they they come from other real life albums. If they come from a real life source, than what are the tracks and albums?

Comment: Have you tried running the tracks past a music identification service such as http://www.soundhound.com/ or http://www.shazam.com/

Comment: The songs on Diamond City Radio are most certainly real songs, I am unsure of classical (I tend not to use it); I would assume so. @DavidYell had a great idea however

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Over at this [Fallout 4 Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_soundtrack) is a list of all songs in Fallout 4. According to this list, the majority of the songs on Diamond City Radio are real songs from the 1930ies to 1960ies.

There are a few songs, sung by the in-game character "Magnolia", that appear on Diamond City Radio. These songs were recorded specifically for the game:

- Baby It's Just You
- Good Neighbor
- I'm the One You're Looking For
- Man Enough
- Train Train

The Classical Radio also seems to feature real songs since there are works from Beethoven, Wagner, Brahms etc.

Answer (score 9):

**The songs you hear on the radio are mostly out-of-verse songs from the 30s-60s, and the classical period.**

In Fallout 4, radio songs are split across 2 radio stations: Diamond City Radio and Classical Radio. Diamond City Radio also plays a series that were written exclusively for Fallout 4 by [Lynda Carter](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0004812/), who voices the in-game singer, [Magnolia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Magnolia).

---

### [Classical Radio](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Classical_Radio)

Classical Radio plays classical music, all of which are real classical pieces from artists such as Johann Sebastian Bach and Ludvig von Beethoven.

> Classical Radio also has ties to the Institute. If you enjoy listening to the Classical Radio station, be advised that destroying the Institute will shut down the radio station, after which classical songs can only be heard from juke boxes.

- **[Diego Masson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diego_Masson)**

  - ***"Valse Diable"*** can be hard to find a recording of, [but is available on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oB3Dd81QJWA).
- **[Bedřich Smetana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bed%C5%99ich_Smetana)**

  - ***"3 Polkas de salon, Op. 7"*** can be hard to find a recording of, [but is available on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0wfvUfeir1k).
- **[Camille Saint-Saëns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camille_Saint-Sa%C3%ABns)**

  - ***"[The Elephant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Carnival_of_the_Animals#V_L.27.C3.A9l.C3.A9phant_.28The_Elephant.29)"** is the 5<sup>th</sup> track on the 2010 album *[The Carnival Of The Animals](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bkktlxokwbvxbwnmrqqjcvodid4&tid=song-T33hes2vrchatftugz2ayblusfq)*.
  - ***"[The Cuckoo in the Depths of the Woods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Carnival_of_the_Animals#IX_Le_coucou_au_fond_des_bois_.28The_Cuckoo_in_the_Depths_of_the_Woods.29)"** is the 9<sup>th</sup> track on the 2010 album *[The Carnival Of The Animals](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bkktlxokwbvxbwnmrqqjcvodid4&tid=song-T33hes2vrchatftugz2ayblusfq)*.
  - ***"[The Swan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Carnival_of_the_Animals#XIII_Le_cygne_.28The_Swan.29)"** is the 13<sup>th</sup> track on the 2010 album *[The Carnival Of The Animals](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bkktlxokwbvxbwnmrqqjcvodid4&tid=song-T33hes2vrchatftugz2ayblusfq)*.
- **[Claude Debussy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_Debussy)**

  - ***"[Jeux de Vagues](https://play.google.com/store/music/album/Claude_Debussy_Le_jeu_des_vagues?id=Bqrktkkas5oejul5abozebctchy)"*** is the 3<sup>rd</sup> track on the 2009 album *[Classical Best](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bh5fste2qzuimormjsf3xwrn77e&tid=song-Tgs4cpwon2q5ovc53zeaksrhuoe)*.
  - ***"[Nuages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nocturnes_%28Debussy%29#Movements)"*** is the 8<sup>th</sup> track on the 2009 album *[Classical Best](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bh5fste2qzuimormjsf3xwrn77e&tid=song-Tgs4cpwon2q5ovc53zeaksrhuoe)*.
- **[Domenico Scarlatti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domenico_Scarlatti)**

  - ***"Keyboard Sonata in F Minor, K. 19"*** is the 5<sup>th</sup> track on the 2015 album *[Classical Selection - Scarlatti: Keyboard Sonatas](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bovqo2cz6ys7wufehpwzguxr3vu&tid=song-Tgd2wgc6gxg43qe5n2essdndxny)*.
- **[Edvard Grieg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edvard_Grieg)**

  - ***"[In the Hall of the Mountain King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_the_Hall_of_the_Mountain_King)"*** is the 8<sup>th</sup> track on the 2007 album *[The Classical Greats Series, Vol. 27: Grieg](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bxajtj54sxi6lxub3t7r6geajbq&tid=song-Twdo25lnmgmkqcjsi65hetbpsha)*.
  - ***"[Morning Mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morning_Mood)"*** is the 7<sup>th</sup> track on the 2013 album *[The Classical Greats Series, Vol. 27: Grieg](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bxajtj54sxi6lxub3t7r6geajbq&tid=song-Twdo25lnmgmkqcjsi65hetbpsha)*.
- **[Edward Elgar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Elgar)**

  - ***"[Nimrod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_Variations#Variation_IX_.28Adagio.29_.27Nimrod.27)**"*** is the 10<sup>th</sup> track on the 2007 album *[A Calendar of Classics - September](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Be5yipoun62w6oxhjwzoez3n7yu&tid=song-Tcqdfsv4zltn76ewbyn6jqrempa)*.
  - ***"[Salut D'Amour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salut_d'Amour)"*** is the 13<sup>th</sup> track on the 2014 album *[Herr Ober, zwei Mokka!](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Btdetnqhwt65tsneu722yzmfm5y&tid=song-Tmbqqzi547po3va2qwajwsjzroy)*.
- **[Franz Liszt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz_Liszt)**

  - ***"[Consolations No. 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolations_%28Liszt%29#Consolation_No._3)"***  is the 10<sup>th</sup> track on the 2010 album *[Classical Piano Chillout 2](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Btuokc24intbnqrf6yyicz3osvy&tid=song-Tisbxn3esbahsjv44ees52caiua)*.
  - ***"[Hungarian Rhapsody No. 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_Rhapsody_No._2)"*** is the 5<sup>th</sup> track on the 2009 album *[The Soloist - Classical Masters](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Butq7re4hhtfocdhg4kgzdqy2ha&tid=song-Tpv7p2refctxns4pfmojjlqopne)*.
- **[Frédéric Chopin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric_Chopin)**

  - ***"[Introduction and Polonaise brillante in C major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_and_Polonaise_brillante_%28Chopin%29)"*** can be hard to find a recording of, [but is available on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WcgnKpCK1Lk).
  - ***"[Nocturne in E-flat major No. 2, Op. 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nocturnes,_Op._9_%28Chopin%29#Nocturne_in_E-flat_major.2C_Op._9.2C_No._2)"***  is the 10<sup>th</sup> track on the 2009 album *[Chopin](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bo6mfxh6cbevowkyi4w6t7dcdue&tid=song-Tqjpaeebazxpkudyebujkbn6w4q)*.
  - ***"[Ballade No. 1 in G minor, Op. 23](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballades_%28Chopin%29#Ballade_No._1)"***  is the 3<sup>rd</sup> track on the 2014 album *[Nocturnes in Chopin](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bx5wfdso2ojdarbqyzwbjdhuqwq&tid=song-Tkmafwuk6nb3qhuiyzmqah4zwje)*.
- **[Gustav Holst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustav_Holst)**

  - ***"[Mars, the Bringer of War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Planets#Structure)"*** is the 1<sup>st</sup> track on the 1987 album *[The Planets](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bkbcovq3jwkbqn5byhdglnahntu&tid=song-Tqf5fsfnbayxc6zogsjvqrrsn4y)*.
- **[Johann Sebastian Bach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Sebastian_Bach)**

  - ***"[Lute Suite in E minor - Courante](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lute_Suite_in_E_minor,_BWV_996)"*** is available in its entirety as the 33<sup>rd</sup> track on the 2009 album *[The 99 Most Essential Bach Masterpieces](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bp3dblzbw4zcck6bf3fw7krcd4i&tid=song-Thpctimlzsi2ypnwlb45nrbgtqy)*.
- **[Johann Strauss II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Strauss_II)**

  - ***"[The Blue Danube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Blue_Danube)"*** is the 7<sup>th</sup> track on the 2011 album *[Wow-Classics Feat. Vivaldi & Schubert](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bb3qehcsdpirndoz3ebwn2audlu&tid=song-Tv7xlgghyznmhokuc3aljixjxfm)*.
- **[Johannes Brahms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johannes_Brahms)**

  - ***"[Tragic Overture, Op. 81](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tragic_Overture_%28Brahms%29)"*** is the 5<sup>th</sup> track on the 20 album *[Blue Edition - Brahms: Waldhorn Trio, Op. 40 & Tragic Overture, Op. 81](https://play.google.com/store/music/album/Dieter_Vorholz_Erich_Penzel_G%C3%BCnter_Ludwig_Vladimir?id=Bw47zs6n6ai6qv567jpxyr2ljda)*.
- **[Ludwig van Beethoven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_van_Beethoven)**

  - ***"String Quartet No. 12 in E-flat major: Maestoso - Allegro"*** is the 7<sup>th</sup> track on the 2016 album *[Orange Edition - Beethoven: Piano Sonata No. 14 "Moonlight" & String Quartet No. 12, Op. 127](https://play.google.com/store/music/album/Fritz_Wunderlich_Josef_Bulva_Rolf_Reinhardt_Alfred?id=Bmiw3dzw3it4lgvdyjczkc6mgqq)*.
- **[Modest Mussorgsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modest_Mussorgsky)**

  - ***"[Gopak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fair_at_Sorochyntsi)"*** is [available as a single](https://play.google.com/store/music/album/Tomislav_Bavnov_Mussorgsky_The_Fair_at_Sorochyntsi?id=Bhorcwmqmnmsutzilnhdawk3yuu).**.
  - ***"Piano Meditation"***  is the 21<sup>st</sup> track on the 2010 album *[Mussorgsky: Pictures at an Exhibition: Promenade and Other Classical Piano Favorites](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bqybhc7lodhbsnweulpkx3c7rca&tid=song-Teeycntgs6rkbo7xzuvrc7ewonq)*.
- **[Nikolai Rimsky-Korsakov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikolai_Rimsky-Korsakov)**

  - ***"[The Sea and Sinbad's Ship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheherazade_%28Rimsky-Korsakov%29)"*** is the 1<sup>st</sup> track on the 2011 album *[Scheherazade](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bgkgm7a4yjt47vidltwe7uuyofu&tid=song-Tjigilaxrfjtijwjiynsrklqta4)*.
- **[Pyotr Ilyich Tchaikovsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyotr_Ilyich_Tchaikovsky)**

  - ***"[Marche Slave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marche_slave)"*** is the 37<sup>th</sup> track on the 2012 album *[The Best of Piotr Ilyich Tchaikovsky](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bjpdafxssrwviyhjogju2zchz7u&tid=song-Tmxy5hrynoqacohsx6f46bnfoq4)*.
  - ***"[Swan Lake Finale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swan_Lake)"***  is the 5<sup>th</sup> track on the 2005 album *[Classical Spectacular](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Brid4z3eknllr3vs2yrukgsxcha&tid=song-Tqu4igxgynqws62y5pxsn23kgyq)*.
- **[Richard Wagner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Wagner)**

  - ***"[Ride of the Valkyries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ride_of_the_Valkyries)"*** is the 3<sup>rd</sup> track on the 20 album *[Greatest Classical Music in Movies](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bvmvvudv6xrlidsg34whlnrwo74&tid=song-Thij7kzpjty4vvcpzowualu5atq)*.
- **[Robert Schumann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Schumann)**

  - ***"[Faust Overture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faust_Overture)"*** is the 13<sup>th</sup> track on the 2010 album *[The 50 Greatest Overtures](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bck4lx3sewliqpgeacrj3gyyiky&tid=song-Tmv3kpqtodtqsf6owc2sdiwypsm)*.

---

### [Diamond City Radio](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Diamond_City_Radio_%28radio%29)

Most of the songs you hear on Diamond City Radio come from between the 30s and 40s. Some recordings are new to Fallout 4, while others have featured in other titles. Diamond City also plays the 5 tracks sung by [Magnolia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Magnolia).

#### Songs new to *Diamond City Radio*

- **[Bing Crosby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bing_Crosby)**

  - ***"[Ac-Cen-Tchu-Ate the Positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ac-Cent-Tchu-Ate_the_Positive)"*** was first released in 1994, and won 1945 best song after appearing in the movie "[*Here Come The Waves*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ac-Cent-Tchu-Ate_the_Positive)". It is the 5<sup>th</sup> track on the 2013 album *[Together with the Andrew Sisters](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=B6fxdy7hhtlcl6hqi7ko5few6ga&tid=song-Tvnmkb6fpw55q56rqslyovs6oz4)*.
- **[Betty Hutton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betty_Hutton)**

  - ***"[He's a Demon, He's a Devil, He's a Doll](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/He%27s_a_Demon,_He%27s_a_Devil,_He%27s_a_Doll)"***  was first released in 1950. It is the 33<sup>rd</sup> track on the 2009 album *[The Best Of](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bxp2sju327jsqnu6r5lp2jo3jni&tid=song-Typ5ubyqe5yyjxg2nal52mzpx6m)*.
  - ***"[It's A Man](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/It%27s_A_Man)"*** was first released in 1951. It is the 49<sup>th</sup> track on the 2009 album *[The Best Of](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bxp2sju327jsqnu6r5lp2jo3jni&tid=song-Typ5ubyqe5yyjxg2nal52mzpx6m)*.
- **[Big Maybelle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Maybelle)**

  - ***"[Whole Lotta Shakin' Goin' On](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whole_Lotta_Shakin'_Goin'_On)"*** was first released as a single in 1955. It is the 24<sup>th</sup> track on the 1994 album *[The Complete Okeh Sessions 1952-1955](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bvbxd57zz4o2wqzhqmbyz4pjdbq&tid=song-Tcrgqyw2dwwauxov4qbuhhb3lhq)*.
- **[Bing Crosby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bing_Crosby) and [The Andrews Sisters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Andrews_Sisters)**

  - ***"[Pistol Packin' Mama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pistol_Packin'_Mama)"*** was first performed in 1943. It is the 5<sup>th</sup> track on the 2012 album *[Isle Of Golden Dreams](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=B6zuuegl2wmth6hnby5etxjypdu&tid=song-Tbuhiqccvefdx67bcydxw5uywiy)*.
- **[Bob Crosby and the Bob-Cats](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=B6zuuegl2wmth6hnby5etxjypdu&tid=song-Tbuhiqccvefdx67bcydxw5uywiy)**

  - ***"[Dear Hearts and Gentle People](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dear_Hearts_and_Gentle_People)"*** was first published in 1949 and was also used in a [trailer for Fallout 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t314wo05ElI). It is the 10<sup>th</sup> track on the 2014 album *[The Complete Standard Transcriptions](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bbgovbfac56uak4s67tkv453hjy&tid=song-Tqnyecnpcndxfprilkrijf22i4q)*.
- **[Connie Allen and the Band](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Connie_Allen)**

  - ***"[Rocket 69](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Rocket_69)"*** was first recorded in 1952. It is the 11<sup>th</sup> track on the 2009 album *[Ultimate Rock N' Roll Drinkers & Sinners](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bk7doasl35gkhnkipysbsj7t4ca&tid=song-T5ng5c7g5mpk33dz2i2iuxb76ly)*.
- **[Dion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dion_DiMucci)**

  - ***"[The Wanderer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wanderer_%28Dion_song%29)"*** was first released as a record in 1961. It is the 1<sup>st</sup> track on the 2012 single re-release *[The Wanderer](https://play.google.com/store/music/album/Dion_The_Wanderer?id=B6uafo5fnxkpbhph3exp3k7rmwm)*.
- **[Ella Fitzgerald](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ella_Fitzgerald)**

  - ***"[Undecided](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecided)"*** was a 1939 cover of a 1938 original. It is the 19<sup>th</sup> track on the 2005 album *[Jazz Classics: Ella Fitzgerald](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bwbe5rrlcwr7wxjd5bvjzptbpw4&tid=song-Tqwju7y2gdmfada7e2j3siot5vu)*.
- **[Elton Britt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elton_Britt)**

  - ***"[Uranium Fever](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Uranium_Fever)"*** was first recorded in 1955. It is the 1<sup>st</sup> track on the 2015 album *[Uranium Fever - Fallout 4 Radio](https://play.google.com/store/music/album/Various_Artists_Uranium_Fever_Fallout_4_Radio?id=B7jyqgyelvshihmvkxfgpdmlmgu)*.
- **[Frankie Carle & His Orchestra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankie_Carle)**

  - ***"[One More Tomorrow](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/One_More_Tomorrow)"*** was first recorded in 1946. It was [re-released as a single](https://play.google.com/store/music/album/Frankie_Carle_One_More_Tomorrow?id=Bhi3faghlw2fmg4jddylwr2egoy).
- **[Johnny Mercer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnny_Mercer)**

  - ***"[Personality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personality_%281946_song%29)"*** was originally performed by [Dorothy Lamour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dorothy_Lamour), in the movie *"[Road to Utopia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_to_Utopia)". It is the 3<sup>rd</sup> track on the 2012 album *[Personality](https://play.google.com/store/music/album/Johnny_Mercer_Personality?id=Bxtgw7auwdircvqs64ue2u3oaua)*.
- **[Louis Jordan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Jordan) & [His Tympany Five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tympany_Five)**

  - ***"[Keep a Knockin' (But You Can't Come In)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keep_A-Knockin')"*** was first recorded by Louis Jordan in 1939, but is accredited to recordings as early as 1928. It is the 13<sup>th</sup> track on the 2006 album *[Selected Hits Vol. 3](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bjmihz4qb7fmupwb5eivjqvo2hi&tid=song-Tjriyqmqwg4272cmrphffjpya4a)*.
- **[Nat King Cole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nat_King_Cole)**

  - ***"[Orange Colored Sky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_Colored_Sky)"*** was first written in 1950, and has been recorded by a variety of artists. It is the 11<sup>th</sup> track on the 2000 album *[The Unforgettable Nat King Cole](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bu3m7x5tlkkjtaerct5jm5j5pnm&tid=song-Tocpcmncj7nzck7k6kvsheork7i)*.
- **[Ray Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_Smith_%28rockabilly_singer%29)**

  - ***"[Right Behind You Baby](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Right_Behind_You_Baby)"*** was first released in 1958. It is the 3<sup>rd</sup> track on the 2010 album *[I'm Right Behind You Baby](https://play.google.com/store/music/album/Ray_Smith_I_m_Right_Behind_You_Baby?id=Bmjelp7jhue7yaw2pampnkjbx3m)*.
- **[Roy Brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roy_Brown_%28blues_musician%29)**

  - ***"[Butcher Pete (Part 2)](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Butcher_Pete_(Part_2))"***  was released in 1949. It is the 47<sup>th</sup> track on the 2015 album *[The Music That Rocked Us - The Cramps - Vol. 1](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bhvujvpzii6tms3pu3xrm26r7ri&tid=song-Tpobmbrbwc7id4lpkoik5wrlqta)*.
  - ***"[Good Rockin' Tonight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_Rocking_Tonight)"*** was first released in 1947. It is the 5<sup>th</sup> track on the 1978 album *[Good Rockin' Tonight](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Baq7irittn35vz6hmt7vcvzeyiy&tid=song-Tcv5iuow6xeh75mkdq2lpkkwle4)*.
- **[Sheldon Allman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheldon_Allman)**

  - ***"[Crawl Out Through The Fallout](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Crawl_Out_Through_The_Fallout)"*** was originally released as a novelty sci-fi song. It is the 8<sup>th</sup> track on the 2006 re-release of *[Folk Songs For The 21st Century](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bjyqk5e7tw4see3w6fz32ku2jky&tid=song-Tsz2rv37mh3xhnrklqnsrs3o7rm)*.
- **[Skeeter Davis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeeter_Davis)**

  - ***"[The End of the World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_End_of_the_World_%28Skeeter_Davis_song%29)"*** was first released in 1962. It is the 9<sup>th</sup> track on the 1995 album *[The Essential Skeeter Davis](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Byses3xvyhrp4t3tqd22dcs5p4m&tid=song-Tpkwhig3uugts2bxgjlhudnz55a)*.
- **[The Dominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billy_Ward_and_his_Dominoes)**

  - ***"[Sixty Minute Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixty_Minute_Man)"*** was first recorded as a single in 1951, and the song is regarded as an influential record in shaping the Rock and Roll genre. It is the 1<sup>st</sup> track on the 2009 album *[14 Greatest Hits](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bmckqvbcxa4zg5q544bfhy34l64&tid=song-Twytvx2rmap37tewxlyfjkeig2u)*.
- **[The Five Stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Five_Stars)**

  - ***"[Atom Bomb Baby](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Atom_Bomb_Baby)"***  was first released in 1957. It is the 9<sup>th</sup> track on the 2015 album *[Uranium Fever - Fallout 4 Radio](https://play.google.com/store/music/album/Various_Artists_Uranium_Fever_Fallout_4_Radio?id=B7jyqgyelvshihmvkxfgpdmlmgu)*.
- **[The Ink Spots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ink_Spots)**

  - ***"[It's All Over But the Crying](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/It's_All_Over_But_the_Crying)"*** was originally recorded in 1944. It is the 12<sup>th</sup> track of the 3<sup>rd</sup>rd disc on the 2015 album *[That Cat Is High](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Brlm4ihiy2yqbhpqicr53efnmq4&tid=song-Tz4v7is3g7hnctst64dnxkt35ba)*.
  - ***"[I Don't Want to Set the World on Fire](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/I_Don't_Want_to_Set_the_World_on_Fire)"*** was first released in 1941, and is possibly one of the most recognised songs in Fallout. It featured in [a Fallout 3 trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uxSdbSNckTQ), and there was [initial intention](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/I_Don't_Want_to_Set_the_World_on_Fire#Background) to use the song as early Fallout 1. It is the 15<sup>th</sup> track of the 2<sup>nd</sup>rd disc on the 2015 album *[That Cat Is High](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Brlm4ihiy2yqbhpqicr53efnmq4&tid=song-Tz4v7is3g7hnctst64dnxkt35ba)*.
- **[The Three Suns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Three_Suns)**

  - ***"[Worry, Worry, Worry](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Worry_Worry_Worry)"*** was first released in 1948. It is the 11<sup>th</sup> track on the 2015 album *[Uranium Fever - Fallout 4 Radio](https://play.google.com/store/music/album/Various_Artists_Uranium_Fever_Fallout_4_Radio?id=B7jyqgyelvshihmvkxfgpdmlmgu)*.
- **[Warren Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warren_Smith_%28singer%29)**

  - ***"[Uranium Rock](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Uranium_Rock)"*** was first released in 1958. It is the 9<sup>th</sup> track on the 2010 album *[Simply Rock'n'Roll Vol. Two](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bt7xdh5qlfb5sleewpi2hrqml4i&tid=song-Ttekxgjczle6s7xekvltcmcfnru)*.
- **[Wynonie Harris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wynonie_Harris)**

  - ***"[Grandma Plays the Numbers](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Grandma_Plays_the_Numbers)"*** was first released in 1949. It is the 13<sup>th</sup> track on the 2015 album *[Uranium Fever - Fallout 4 Radio](https://play.google.com/store/music/album/Various_Artists_Uranium_Fever_Fallout_4_Radio?id=B7jyqgyelvshihmvkxfgpdmlmgu)*.

#### Songs from *Galaxy News Radio*

The following songs were also played on *Galaxy News Radio* in Fallout 3.

- **[Cole Porter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cole_Porter)**

  - ***"[Anything Goes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anything_Goes_%28Cole_Porter_song%29)"*** was first released in 1934, [in a musical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anything_Goes). It is the 24<sup>th</sup> track on the 2012 album [*Early Big Band Hits, Vol 2*](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bzkp3oususyp6dn7wgpafllvgv4&tid=song-Tjq2mxvuog36jmhtjdhpih27w74&hl=en)
- **[Oscar Hammerstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscar_Hammerstein_II)**

  - ***"[A wonderful Guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I'm_in_Love_with_a_Wonderful_Guy)"*** was first released in 1949, [in a musical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Pacific_%28musical%29). It is the 20<sup>th</sup> track on the 2012 album *[South Pacific](https://play.google.com/store/music/album/Oscar_Hammerstein_II_Richard_Rodgers_South_Pacific?id=Beawfnaq2arkuyi7ghljuwhsu7a)*.
- **[Billie Holiday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billie_Holiday)**

  - ***"[Crazy He Calls Me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crazy_He_Calls_Me)"*** was originally written in 1949. It is the 2<sup>nd</sup> track on the 2016 album *[The Great Lyricists - Carl Sigman](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Byerhidesumx5yqo6rnj3nrdf3i&tid=song-Tjw6r27begihidmhjjejpmroyji)*.
  - ***"[Easy Living](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easy_Living_%28song%29)"*** was originally written in 1937. It is the 11<sup>th</sup> track on the 2015 album *[Lo Mejor del Jazz](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Boekgzctxdjg7nekbfmazs2filq&tid=song-Temyslgoyu2jdnqfpif5p6y6boe)*.
- **[Bob Crosby and the Bobcats](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=B6zuuegl2wmth6hnby5etxjypdu&tid=song-Tbuhiqccvefdx67bcydxw5uywiy)**

  - ***"[Happy Times](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Happy_Times)"*** was first released in 1949. It is the 12<sup>th</sup> track on the 2014 album *[The Complete Standard Transcriptions](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bbgovbfac56uak4s67tkv453hjy&tid=song-Tqnyecnpcndxfprilkrijf22i4q)*.
  - ***"[Way Back Home](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Way_Back_Home)"*** was first released in 1935. It is the 2<sup>nd</sup> track on the 2014 album *[The Complete Standard Transcriptions](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bbgovbfac56uak4s67tkv453hjy&tid=song-Tqnyecnpcndxfprilkrijf22i4q)*.
- **[Roy Brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roy_Brown_%28blues_musician%29)**

  - ***"[Butcher Pete (Part 1)](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Butcher_Pete_(Part_1))"*** was released in 1949. It is the 46<sup>th</sup> track on the 2015 album *[The Music That Rocked Us - The Cramps - Vol. 1](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bhvujvpzii6tms3pu3xrm26r7ri&tid=song-Tpobmbrbwc7id4lpkoik5wrlqta)*.
  - ***"[Mighty, Mighty Man](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Mighty,_Mighty_Man)"*** was first released in 1948. It is the 2<sup>nd</sup> track of the 2013 album *[Good Rockin' Tonight](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bjsi2p4nohrg6a733g2orfxqju4&tid=song-Tx5ljz454sxykxktsu2vn5snvom)*
- **[The Andrew Sisters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Andrews_Sisters) and [Danny Kaye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danny_Kaye)**

  - ***"[Civilization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civilization_(1947_song))"*** was first released in 1947. It is the 5<sup>th</sup> track on the 2013 album *[Greatest Pop Hits of the 40's & 50's, Vol. 2](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Btrpdoeicp235didxwspmyocfoa&tid=song-Tqqg6465jdnmav5vssix76gtw4q)*.
- **[The Ink Spots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ink_Spots)**

  - ***"[Into Each Life Some Rain Must Fall](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Into_Each_Life_Some_Rain_Must_Fall)"*** was originally recorded in 1944, with Ella Fitzgerald. It is the 2<sup>nd</sup> track on the 2011 album *[Songs of Doris Fisher](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bo3qzxujmqrfcriv4jey7fgkfe4&tid=song-Tcxtjwpwu4ev27fstdoak7ylhzm)*.
  - ***"[Maybe](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Maybe)"*** was first released in 1940. It is the 3<sup>rd</sup> track on the 2013 album *[Maybe and Other Doo Wop Favourites](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bgtrs5k3phjnhpn6en7pxo7mymi&tid=song-Tjz4cvt7bt5lzujmjnxpjnxltci)*.

#### Songs by *[Magnolia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Magnolia)*

The songs sung by Magnolia were recorded exclusively for Fallout 4 by the characters voice actress, [Lynda Carter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynda_Carter). Lynda Carter has previously played Wonder Woman, and provided voice acting for Skyrim.

The songs are also attributed to John Jarvis and Kerry Max, and do not appear to have been released anywhere but in game.

- ***"[Baby It's Just You](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Baby_It%27s_Just_You)"***
- ***"[Good Neighbour](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Good_Neighbor)"***
- ***"[I'm the One You're Looking For](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/I%27m_the_One_You%27re_Looking_For)"***
- ***"[Man Enough](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Man_Enough)"***
- ***"[Train Train](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Train_Train)"***

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For example, two of the original theme songs from Fallout 2 and 3, *Maybe* and *I don’t want to set the world* on fire, are works of *Ink Spot*, a band from 1930s. Bethesda has also included many other Ink Spot’s songs, along with some other mid 1900 songs.

Comment: Don't forget Louis Armstrong's _A Kiss to Build a Dream On_ from Fallout 2.